# Angular.js memory leak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I recently found thing that looks like memory leak in my angular app, memory consumption constantly increased when route changed.

So, to find out if problem is in my code, i decided to step aside from it and create sample app.

1. git clone github.com/angular/angular-seed.git
2. npm start
3. open chrome, start recording memory timeline
4. try to switch between screens couple times

Here is what i observed in timeline afterwards:
[timeline screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agsr1.png)
(error in console is related to absent favicon :) )

Does anyone know what is the cause of this behavior?

UPD: I made test with same app without angular-router(i thought that it can be cause). I just copied content of views into index.html, and added ng-show conditions for local variable "screen" set by ng-click on "view1" and "view2"

Here is what i got: [timeline screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yWrT.png)

Comment: I think you might want to report it.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this before in a few Angular apps. Most of the time it happens when Angular calls lots of unnecessary digest loops to check for changes and update the DOM from $scope data, or however you are tying the $scope to your controllers.

In most cases, you can do a better job of ensuring that only the data you need is in the current scope and to not make Angular unnecessarily keep track of lots of data points that you aren't using.

Try installing a chrome extension like ng-inspector: http://ng-inspector.org/ or AngularJS Batarang:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Both of these can give you more information about what data is consuming memory and how digest loops play a role in that. From there, it might require changes to the way you have structured your app or choice about what data is passed into your controllers and tied to the view.

I'm interested to see what other types of answers get posted for this question and if anyone more familiar with Angular2 knows if this has been solved with the new version.